# About linux processes running on self-discovery

Tags: linux, service

Is there an open source tool that can auto-discover what services are running on the server?

My Scenario: The company has too many servers and often forgets which services have been configured. When the server is down, it leads to blind spots, which in turn leads to failure to restore services in time.

Thinks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com